# Clarification about the condition for Community user deletion

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-questions

This is the condition at the timing of writing as cited from [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).

> **If the question is more than `30` days old, and ...**
>
> - has −1 or lower score
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
>
> **...or...**
>
> - it was closed and migrated to a different site
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted.
>
> **If the question is more than `365` days old, and ...**
>
> - has a score of 0 *or* a score of 1 with a deleted owner
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
> - has a viewcount <= the age of the question in days times 1.5
> - has 1 or 0 comments
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted.
>
> These checks are run every week across all sites.
>
> **If the question was closed more than `9` days ago, and ...**
>
> - not closed as a duplicate
> - has a score of 0 or less
> - is not locked
> - has no answers with a score > 0
> - has no accepted answer
> - has no pending reopen votes
> - has not been edited in the past `9` days
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted:

However, I observe that some of the open questions from [Anime & Manga](http://anime.stackexchange.com) with +0/-0 vote got roomba-ed by Community user after one year, even though the owner is not deleted.

Some examples:

- [What position does the village chief have when he's not a kappa?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5305/what-position-does-the-village-chief-have-when-hes-not-a-kappa)
- [What kind of sins would determine if a Prinny is sent to the Netherworld or Celestia?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7074/what-kind-of-sins-would-determine-if-a-prinny-is-sent-to-the-netherworld-or-cele)
- [Can a Burst Warrior use any Burst Heart?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7102/can-a-burst-warrior-use-any-burst-heart)

All those questions are not closed (which doesn't fit the 3rd rule), and their scores are 0 at the time of Community deletion (which doesn't fit the 1st rule), and the fact that they are deleted roughly 1 year after suggests that the 2nd rule is invoked. However, **the questions are not attached to a deleted owner**. So is this a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) in the script, or [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) (in which case the post above needs to be updated)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you have parsed

> has a score of 0 or a score of 1 with a deleted owner

as

> (has a score of 0 or a score of 1) with a deleted owner

But the intended (and correct) meaning of that clause is

> has a score of 0 or (a score of 1 with a deleted owner)

Comment: Oh, right, there was italic formatting on `or`, but I didn't notice it since the number of characters is too few.